# Deluge won't run stand alone

Tags: bittorrent, deluge

I install Deluge on Ubuntu and it comes up in thin client mode.  I go into settings to change it to stand alone and when it restarts I get a message saying `Only thin client mode is available due to unknown import error`.

It also tells me to check logs for the error if I want to run in stand-alone.

First, I have no idea what logs the message is talking about.  Next, if anyone else has gone through this problem and resolve it I would greatly appreciate the help.

I did check syslog (what I did is go to var/log, then start deluge and look for logs that have changed and that's the only one that changed under that directory)

and I got these lines, along with hundreds of others related to what looks like producing the application GUI:

```
Aug 6 18:10:44 xxxxxxx dbus-daemon[974]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.112' (uid=1000 pid=4092 comm="deluge-gtk                           " label="unconfined")

Aug  6 18:10:44 xxxxxxx systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...

Aug  6 18:10:44 xxxxxxx dbus-daemon[974]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'

Aug  6 18:10:44 xxxxxxx systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.

Aug  6 18:11:14 xxxxxxx systemd[1]: systemd-hostnamed.service: Succeeded.
```

There is `xxxxxxxx` in place where my `PC ID` would be.

I looked as best I could for any type of log file under deluge directory structure but didn't see anything, or any file that looked like it changed based on when I started Deluge.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you install Deluge?
This is the universal command. Do not desist, it is a great torrent client :)

     sudo apt-get install deluge

Comment: I'm running this under Ubuntu MATE.  I installed using the Software search tool that runs from the desktop.  The Software search tool is a GUI and it says its source is the Ubuntu repository.    This is the package:  lp_ppa_deluge_team_stable-eoan-main

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and installed it the same way you did. I even removed it, and installed again, no joy.

I then installed over the top of the software store installation using the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install deluge
```

Now it works as expected.

Comment: So, you are saying that you first installed using the software store (or the GUI repository for lack of a better term), and then without uninstalling it, you ran the command line to install?

Comment: I had the same issue. After installing it from __"Ubuntu Software"__ i got the error, i uninstalled and then installed via __sudo apt-get install deluge__ and now it works as it should. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Same problem here on POP_OS 20.04 (an Ubuntu fork). Thin Mode only and would not connect.

Solved as follows.

- Uninstall with terminal (or package manager)

`sudo apt-get remove deluge`

- Uninstall also using the software store
- Delete config folder ~/.config/deluge
- Install as advised here,

https://dev.deluge-torrent.org/wiki/Installing/Linux/Ubuntu#AddDelugePPARepository

which is in terminal, using

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deluge-team/stable`

`sudo apt-get update`

`sudo apt-get install deluge`

Then it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve this problem with

```
sudo apt install deluge
```

which added several packages (libboost-python1.74.0 libtorrent-rasterbar2.0 python3-libtorrent) that are not installed with just the -gkt front end/thin client necessary to connect to a server, i.e., when installed with

```
sudo apt install deluge-gtk
```